# Did I just edit waaay too many posts?

Tags: discussion, editing

I was correcting formatting, spelling, grammar, etc. on a lot of old posts (and new ones too) so the question would be clearer. Now the site's front page looks like this:

[image]

Did I do anything wrong to the site?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As long as your edits are constructive, there's nothing wrong with doing a lot of them